# Can I replace the screen with JS or HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Is it possible to use Javascript or HTML to change the the HTML contents?

For example, I have

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>
Click the button below to go to page two.
<button type="button" onclick="gotopage2">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am trying to make it to where when the button is clicked, the page changes to:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>
Welcome to page 2!
</body>
</html>
```

That way, a user can simply click the button and have the page seemingly change without having to load a new page. Like going into a house on a video game.

This is for a mini webapp I'm making, so that when a user clicks an icon, it takes them to a new screen depicting an image and a body of text.

Comment: Look up innerHTML via the search engine of your choice... Or Ajax.

Comment: Replace the innerhtml of body on click of button using javacscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```js
function load_html() {
  $("html").html("<head><title>Hello!</title></head><body>Welcome to page 2!</body></html>");
  //or another file then use
  //$( "html" ).load( "/resources/load.html html" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>
  Click the button below to go to page two.
  <button type="button" onclick="load_html()">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use the innerHTML property to change the html element value,
make use the following code sample.

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Welcome to page 2!";
}
</script>
```

```html
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body id="demo">
Click the button below to go to page two.
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for my purpose. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you'e going to be swapping out a lot of content or multiple pages worth you could use Jquery's `.load()` to replace the content with a different file:

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  Click the button below to go to page two.
  <button type="button" class="replace">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$(".replace").click(function(){
  $(".content").load( "file.html" );
});
```

otherwise you can just have the text in a variable and swap it like so:

```
$(".replace").click(function(){
  var text = "Welcome to page 2!"
  $(".content").html(text);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x50vjk9o/1/)

Or you could just use `innerHTML` like Manu K M suggested if you want a pure Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Just try this,you just need to Id for your body and in your onclick function should be **onclick="gotopage2()"** instead of **onclick="gotopage2"**

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id = 'newPage'>
Click the button below to go to page two.
<button type="button" onclick="gotopage2()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
function gotopage2() 
{
var text = "Welcome to page 2!"
$("#newPage").html(text);
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to only work with Text. I need page 2 to have more buttons.